# CodeIgniter URI routing (dynamic, multilingual)

Tags: codeigniter, routes, multilingual

I'm trying to redirect all routs to one main controller. Here is my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";

//$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';
//$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];

$route['(en|ge)/(:any)'] = $route['default_controller']."/index/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = $route['default_controller']."/index/$1";
```

I need language id to be passed with every link (like: http://site.com/en/hello-world)

Here is my main controller:

```
class Main extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();       
    }

    function index($page_type=false, $param=false) 
    {
        die($page_type.' | '.$param.'| Aaa!');  
    }
}
```

I want to check if predefined file type exists (like: http://site.com/en/archive/05-06-2010 - here predefined type would be archive) then do something. If not then search in the database for slug. If not found then go to 404.

The problem is that I can't get index function parameters ($page_type, $param). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you can see the routing is working correclty, try using `$this->uri->segment(n)` instead? Where n is the number of the segment you are getting from the URI, i.e. http://site.com/1/2/3/4/...

I have seen problems using the implicit parameters of methods like you are using.

For more information, see the CodeIgniter User Guide - the URI Class here:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Best of luck.